# how to detect circle in binary image RGB?

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have the following image:

https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2014/10/18/binkq27dd30.png

I want to count how many circles in my images. My image is nxn 8-bit binary image, not 0 and 1.
So, what can I do ?
Thank you for reading !

Comment: I see 0 circles.  Very grainy.  This will be a super PITA even for a human being with a well-defined definition of a circle in terms of such an image.

Comment: From the looks of you're image, you want Optical Mark Recognition (OMR). One possibility would be http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36378/Optical-Mark-Recognition-with-DotImage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cut down version of: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36378/Optical-Mark-Recognition-with-DotImage

```
//Create a Bitmap object from an image file.
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("Answers.jpg");

//Check the pixels in the Bitmap for the circles:
for (int i = 0; i < myBitmap.Width;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myBitmap.Height;j++)
    {
        Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
        //Translate pixel to a 1 or 0 depending on if the pixel is black or white
        //This next line is psuedo code:
        boolArray[i][j] = pixelColour.R < 128 && pixelColour.G < 128 && pixelColour.B < 128;
    }
}
```

Then iterate through boolen array seeing if you have three or four 1's in a row and above and below, eg:

```
if (boolArray[i][j] && boolArray[i + 1][j] && boolArray[i + 2][j])
{
   if (boolArray[i][j + 1] && boolArray[i][j + 2] && boolArray[i][j + 3])
   {
    //found an answer marked as a filled in circle
   }
}
```

Note: You should check for cicles in the same nested loop. I only populated a multi-dimensional bool Array so you could see the two pieces of logic.